# How to copy files in Angular

Tags: angular, file, copy

Is there a way in Angular to copy files from one location to another?

The closest thing I can file do this is angular.copy(...) but that seems to be more for copying in-memory objects, not files on disc.

There's also the node package copyfile but that seems to be a CLI utility. I want to write a program that copies files according to a config file.

Can Angular do this?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Angular has no more ability to access the file system than javascript does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a client side framework. Which means it runs on browser and you should not expect an API from angular to access on disc.